# Symfony4 'ERROR : Variable does not exist', when i call a variable in my template

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm blocked on error with Symfony 4.3.

I have installed the bundle :
CMENGoogleChartsBundle

Installation is ok, no errors.

So i wanted try it, i have create a new controller "TestChartController" and a new template "testChart/index.html.twig".

I have use the code of tutorial :
https://github.com/cmen/CMENGoogleChartsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/basic_usage.md

The Case 1.

Here is i have in my IDE :

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Charts\PieChart;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Environment;

class TestChartController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var Environment
     **/
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test/chart", name="testChart")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('testChart/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'TestChartController',
        ]);
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $pieChart = new PieChart();
        $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
            [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Work',     11],
                ['Eat',      2],
                ['Commute',  2],
                ['Watch TV', 2],
                ['Sleep',    7]
            ]
        );
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setTitle('My Daily Activities');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setHeight(500);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setWidth(900);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setBold(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setColor('#009900');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setItalic(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontName('Arial');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontSize(20);

        return $this->render('testChart/index.html.twig', ['piechart' => $pieChart]);
    }
}
```

**Template** :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello TestChartController !{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
        <!-- index.html.twig -->
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <div id="div_chart"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            {{ gc_draw(piechart, 'div_chart') }}
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
    {% endblock %}
```

But Symfony response with fatal error :

[Img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keL5K.png)

I  have tryed with a simple string in my controller :

`$test = 'test'`
And i ave modified the render :

`return $this->render('testChart/index.html.twig', ['test' => $test]);`

Finally i have `dump(test)` in my template.

Same error.

NB: All other templates function correctly.

Thx for your future help.

RESOLVE: Moove this on the second function indexAction

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/chart", name="testChart")
 */
```

Symfony 4.3.2

W10

Comment: The other function gets executet. The @Route is placed at the first function 'index()', move it to the second function 'indexAction()'.

Comment: Many thanks Vyctorya, you have the good answer ! You win a big hug from France, thx !

Answer (score 0):

Try using this controller.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Charts\PieChart;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Environment;

class TestChartController extends AbstractController
{


    /**
     * @var Environment
     **/
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test/chart", name="testChart")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pieChart = new PieChart();
        $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
            [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Work',     11],
                ['Eat',      2],
                ['Commute',  2],
                ['Watch TV', 2],
                ['Sleep',    7]
            ]
        );
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setTitle('My Daily Activities');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setHeight(500);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setWidth(900);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setBold(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setColor('#009900');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setItalic(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontName('Arial');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontSize(20);

        return $this->render(
            'testChart/index.html.twig', [
                'piechart' => $pieChart
            ]
        );
    }
}
```